# How to replace a superscript character in a string in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have to parse a text file that has values such as m² and 100in². While running the code I am testing a string for these. The test fails because "sometimes" it sees that characters as 'm�' or '100in�'. When I first wrote it with the superscript in the test string "If line.Contains("100in²") then..." it worked a few times but then it choked and the strings were no longer represented the same way in code so the test did not see in² it saw in�. So how can I test the string to see if it contains the superscript in a way that is consistent and bomb proof?

Comment: What encoding was used to save the file? Use the same encoding when you read it back. Possibly, use Encoding.UTF-8 in any case (not Encoding.Default, or ASCII).

Comment: Can the superscript only be 2?

Comment: This could be a code page issue or a font issue.  If that's the case, checking the string won't help, because you'll still see what appears to be the correct character, but it won't appear correctly in your UI.

Answer (score 0):

Check asc code of �, and then use this asc code parsing your file.

Comment: The ASCII code is 253 and was not recognized.

Comment: The �is a special character used to indicate a character is not implemented in a code set.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shown ANY code it is hard to give a good answer.  Here is some code that might spark some ideas.

```
    Debug.WriteLine("")
    Dim path As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    path = IO.Path.Combine(path, "test.txt")
    'round trip text to file
    Dim s As String = "⁰¹²⁴m² and 100in²"
    Dim t As String = s
    IO.File.WriteAllText(path, t)
    t = IO.File.ReadAllText(path)
    If t <> s Then Stop

    For Each c As Char In s
        Debug.WriteLine("'  {0} {1}", c, AscW(c))
    Next
    ' CH  Dec. code
    '  ⁰ 8304
    '  ¹ 185
    '  ² 178
    '  ⁴ 8308
    '  m 109
    '  ² 178
    '    32
    '  a 97
    '  n 110
    '  d 100
    '    32
    '  1 49
    '  0 48
    '  0 48
    '  i 105
    '  n 110
    '  ² 178

    Dim superSCRs As String = "⁰¹²³⁴"
    For Each super As Char In superSCRs
        If s.Contains(super) Then
            Stop
        End If
    Next
```